# using the presto-client-node docs aren't clear for me

Tags: javascript, node.js, presto

I am trying to use the following [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/presto-client) to connect to a presto db in Node.

This is what I have so far.

```js
const presto = require('presto-client')

const client = new presto.Client({
  host: 'xxx-presto-da.xxx.com',
  port: 1234,
  catalog: 'gridhive',
  schema: 'rpt',
  source: 'nodejs-client',
  basic_auth: {user: 'xxx', password: 'xxx'},
})

const getPrestoData = () => {
  client.execute({
    query: `
      select some query
    `,
    data: function (error, data, columns, stats) {
      console.log('data:', data)
      return data
    },
    success: function (error, stats) {},
  })
}

console.log(getPrestoData())
```

But this is what's returned

```bash
13:56:15 in sellersjson-analysis/src/lib via ⬢ v18.3.0 
> node presto.js
undefined
```

I am not sure what is being undefined. I just want to know the best way to implement this. Am I doing it correctly?

Comment: `getPrestoData` does not `return` anything. You `return` something from the `data` callback only, but `execute` will ignore that

Comment: so how do i do that? how do i return the data callback?

Comment: See the duplicate: you don't. Either accept a callback or build a promise for it.